# How do pageActions and browserActions differ?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a writing a chrome extension that allows users to do the following:

1. Load data into the popup when the icon is clicked
2. Change the data in the popup based on actions the user takes on the page
3. Append elements to the DOM of the page based on actions taken in the popup

It seems that I can accomplish 1 with a script in the `browser_action` field of the manifest, but perhaps I need a `page_action` script for 2 and 3?

The core of the problem is that I do not know *exactly* how `browser_actions` and `page_actions` differ from each other. My limited understanding is that page actions allow data populated in the popup to be manipulated dynamically. Is this true? I cannot find an explanation about the differences that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Browser Action** is a type of extensions that use icon on the right of address bar. You click on that icon and popup page is loading. Those extensions work *regardless of page currently opened*.
[image]

**Page Action** only works while certain webpage(s) is opened. It displays as an icon inside the address bar (near page URL). This is for extensions only working on *certain websites*.
[image]

If you want to make your extension working on every website, you should use browser_action.

For further information you may want to visit these pages:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html